# Search for a string in the output of a command

Tags: shell-script

I'm stuck with a simple script. I want to run `tracepath` on multiple address and to find if some IP is contained in the output of the `tracepath`. For now I have the following:

```
if tracepath -n google.com | grep x.x.x.x 
do 
echo bal bal 
else 
echo ova ova ova
fi
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: what are you trying to grep for? your regexp says 'x' then any character then 'x' …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this syntax and I think you don't want the output of `grep`, so we use the `-q` (quiet) switch:

```
(traceroute -n google.com | grep -q x.x.x.x) && echo "Yes" || echo "Nope"
```

Or with the `if` statement:

```
if (traceroute -n google.com | grep -q x.x.x.x)
then
  echo "Yes"
else
 echo "Nope"
fi
```

Comment: Yup it work perfect ! Im trying now to put the echo in newline, i have the following ... `echo "This $i is OK"` and $i is the ip address so when i use "\n" it does not work and when i use '' instead of "" the $i is showing instead of the actual ip addrees ( or value )

Comment: Found solution about this too ... echo -e "This $i is OK \n" :)

Comment: The parentheses are superfluous. @user3523605

Answer (score -1):

You have wrong syntax, after `if` condition there should be `then`, not `do`:

```
tracepath -n google.com | grep x.x.x.x
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "bal bal" 
else
echo "ova ova ova"
fi
```

Comment: -1 as rude your code is equivalent.

Comment: This code is exactly equivalent to the code in the question.

Comment: @Gilles Oh is it???? I've tried it out for real. Code in the question doesnt work, but mine works. What is this `do` doing in the `if-else` statement???

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yes, `do` should be `then`. Your answer would be useful if it pointed that out instead of insulting the asker.